# WebGL lighting isn't applied to some edges?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, lighting

No idea what this is called, but when viewing my model at a distance, it doesn't look like the lighting is being applied to some of the edges, which makes them stand out. Any ideas? I'm not using any textures.

Vertex Shader:

```
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec3 aNormal;

uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;

varying vec3 vLighting;

void main(void) {
  vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  vec3 directionalLight = vec3(1.0, 0.5, 0.5);
  vec3 directionalLightDirection = vec3(0.8, 0.7, 0.6);

  vec4 transformedNormal = uNormalMatrix * vec4(aNormal, 1.0);
  float directional = max(dot(transformedNormal.xyz, directionalLightDirection), 0.0);
  vLighting = ambientLight + (directionalLight * directional);

  gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aPosition / 80.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 vLighting;

void main(void) {
  vec4 skin = vec4(0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(skin.rgb * vLighting, skin.a);
}
```

Picture:

[image: Issue]
[image: Zoomed in]

Comment: I fail to see the problem you have described here.

Comment: I'll post another picture. If you look closely at the picture you'll see the model's edges are dark.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I've posted a zoomed in image where the problem is clearer.

Comment: Are you sure your model doesn't have cracks in it?

Comment: @JosephHelfert: I hadn't considered that, but I really don't think so.

Comment: I would check the model for polygons with only 2 vertex or edge shared with more than 2 polygons.

Comment: This is not a shader problem.